# How to resolve "dynamic" dependencies with laravel 5.5 service container?

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently developing a CMS package, similar to the django's administration site, for laravel.

What I'm trying to achieve is the feature on django where you can simply create a class to build a model block on the admin panel, specifically for the relationships on any model.

With that said, to show any model on the admin panel it's necessary to create a class, just like django's, and provide a little configuration.

This is where the things become a little messy.

Let's say that there are two classes:

```
class PermissionAdmin extends Admin{}
class RoleAdmin extends Admin {}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'DashboardController@method'); //Show model list
Route::post('/{slug}', 'DashboardController@method'); //Create a new instance of a model
Route::get('/{slug}/{id}', 'DashboardController@method'); //Show a model
Route::post('/{slug}/{id}', 'DashboardController@realMethod'); //Updates a model
```

Now we're going to focus on `DashboardController@realMethod`

Controller:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {

    function realMethod(Request $request, $slug, $id){
        $className = ucfirst($slug)."Admin";
        $ModelAdmin = class_lookup($className);
    }

}
```

class_lookup definition:

```
function class_lookup($class_name){
    if(class_exists($class_name))
        return new $class();
    else if(class_exists("Package\\Namespace\\".$class_name)){
        $class = "Package\\Namespace\\".$class_name;
        return new $class();
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception("Class not found");
    }
}
```

So, if we want to see the list of permissions available, we need to go to `localhost/permission`, the same for the roles: `localhost/roles`. The slug is what I use to search on the default laravel app directory or in the vendor directory. When the dependency is "solved" the process, (create, update) is able to continue.

I want to enhance that dependency process and maybe with service container bindings it's possible but I'm still trying to figure out.

It will be great if I could have something like this:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {

    function realMethod(ModelAdmin $model){
            $modelAdmin = $model;
            ......
    }
}
```

in order to avoid repeating the `class_lookoup($className)` on every method of the controller.

You guys know any way to make it work like that?